# Simulating mouse clicks from service

Tags: android, service, mouse, simulate

I am looking forums for two days now and can't find the answer. I am new to android and i have a problem. I need to have a small server service in backround (which i have) that gets coordinates for example. With that coordinates i must simulate (make) a click on the active activity... 
It should be service for controling the android from the computer. The computer client aplication sends some information like pressed key or mouse click and the service gets it and performs action on active activity.
Is there any way to do that , some example or something ? Thank you

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible due to obvious security risks.

Comment: could you explain why it isn't possible, you're answer doesn't help us at all... what are these security risks that you have mentioned?

Comment: It is not possible because Android is designed in a way to prevent this behaviour due to the security risks mentioned. If this would be possible, any app could act like the actual owner of the phone - and execute malicious actions. Which can involve countless attack vectors. E.g. apps could open the SMS app and send hundreds of SMS to "premium" services *(without even the SMS permission)*, costing the user lots of money. Or you could bypass the confirmation dialog that pops up when a app tries to enable bluetooth programatically. And I'm pretty sure my imagination is limited in that regard.

Comment: But what if we rooted the android ? Is there anyway then ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to test your activity, have a look at TouchUtils:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/TouchUtils.html

Comment: Not actually trying to test activity. We are trying to simulate click in active activity from service. Is that possible and how ?

Comment: can you explain why do you have to simulate click from a service ? may be there is an other way to do what you want without simulating a click

Comment: I am building application for controling android from pc without USB. I need something like MonkeyRunners methods for simulating clicks, is there anyway to do such thing ?